# New relic custom plugin data not showing up - ruby sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, newrelic-platform

I am using newrelic's ruby sdk to develop a custom plugin. When I run the sample app, on the terminal it shows that the data is successfully captured. But when i go to the site, it cannot search the metrics and due to that I cannot look at any data reported.

the plugin name and everthing else shows up but don't where the data is going.

This what the agent file looks like:

```html
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"

require "newrelic_plugin"

module ExampleAgent

  class Agent < NewRelic::Plugin::Agent::Base

    agent_guid "com.phytel.Product1"
    agent_version "1.0.1"
    agent_config_options :hostname  # frequency of the periodic functions
    agent_human_labels("Product1") { "Call Statuses" }

    def poll_cycle
      # x = Time.now.to_f * hertz * Math::PI * 2
      report_metric "Component/Status/Progressing",     "Value", 10
      report_metric "Component/Status/Scheduled",     "Value", 20
      report_metric "Component/Status/Busy",     "Value", 2
    end

  end

  #
  # Register this agent with the component.
  # The ExampleAgent is the name of the module that defines this
  # driver (the module must contain at least three classes - a
  # PollCycle, a Metric and an Agent class, as defined above).
  #
  NewRelic::Plugin::Setup.install_agent :example, ExampleAgent

  #
  # Launch the agent; this never returns.
  #
  NewRelic::Plugin::Run.setup_and_run

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the `Component` part in your metric name.  The SDK automatically adds that for you.